# Where is the Code Analysis (FxCop) function in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, fxcop

I've read that FxCop is integrated in to Visual Studio 2008 out of the box as "Code Analysis".  I can't find how to run the analysis though.  **Where is the "Run Code Analysis" function?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, available in Analyze menu.  But only in the Team System edition.